# How to register C++ function to scxml ecmascript data model?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5, scxml

**This question is deprecated**

I have since converted my state machines to use an extra state to call the C++ function on enter and I trigger `sendEvent`  when the function returns a value.

**Old question is as follows:**

I have a simple SCXML model designed in Qt. It is lacking some functionality such as listening to pub/sub queues, for which I want to register some functions into the `QScxmlStateMachine` instance so I can call them from the ECMAScript portion of the state machine. I took a look at the `QScxmlEcmaScriptDataModel`, but I don't understand how I can modify the evaluate functions to register callbacks. Is it possible to register C++ functions and callbacks to Qt scxml state machines? If so, how?

Additional information:

I created a class called `RegisterJs`, this is `registerjs.h`

```
#ifndef REGISTERJS_H
#define REGISTERJS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class RegisterJS : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RegisterJS(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void showMessage(QString message);
signals:

public slots:
};

static QObject *registerJSProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    RegisterJS *singletonClass = new RegisterJS();
    return singletonClass;
}

#endif // REGISTERJS_H
```

This is `registerjs.cpp`

```
#include "registerjs.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

RegisterJS::RegisterJS(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void RegisterJS::showMessage(QString message){
    QMessageBox::information(0, message, message);
}
```

This is how I register the class:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<RegisterJS>("in.nurett", 1, 0, "RegisterJS", registerJSProvider);
```

This is the content of testflow.js:

```
function testShowMessage() { RegisterJS.showMessage("test"); }
```

This is the relevant content from testflow.scxml:

```
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" version="1.0" binding="early" xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext" name="teststate" qt:editorversion="4.6.2" initial="initialize">
    <state id="initialize">
        <onentry>
            <script>testShowMessage();</script>
        </onentry>
    </state>
    <script src=":testflow.js"/>
```

But the information message doesn't show up.

Comment: The SCXML model uses the common JS runtime shared with QML, IIRC. So do it as you would in QML (Qt Quick).

Comment: @KubaOber so it is as simple as encapsulating the member function inside a `QObject` derived type and calling `qmlRegisterType` on it?

Comment: Yes. Nothing SCXML-specific at all

Comment: @KubaOber I added sample code, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @KubaOber I read the source code, scxml instantiates it's own QJSEngine (see assertEngine() in source code) so I can't just register to qml and hope it will be used from scxml.

Comment: That's a bit of a bummer then. It's possible to get the pointer to that engine though, I'm sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hidden behind a pimpl. I can only get it by modifying the code and recompiling Qt. Or maybe some sort of template hack that erases private modifier.